# How Infinispan Can Use in Data Persistence?

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

I'm Very New to Infinispan Framework.I want To  Know can Infinispan Use For Cashed Entities Data Syncronization with Oracle database tables. Simple scenario is This When I Put an Entity into Cache I want to Persist That entity into Database  without persisting It in to the Database(only puting to Cache) .what I am looking for is a slightly different cache store. The idea behind it is to have the data stored as if we used Hibernate JPA . So the cache store needs to update the right table/row depending on the information of the map key and/or information gained from the JPA annotationsPlease let me know Infinispan Supports this scenario or not?If Supports Please share some sample code with me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html) which allows you to store data into a data grid, such as Infinispan, instead of the database, while using the JPA API?

Comment: Think I have Two Main applications one is Highly Concurrent use app and Other is used as Admin module .Since it is highly concrrent I want To reduse Database connections (Load the entities into cache (read write enable) and Use it from There without calling database).But mean Time I want to Update Database according to The cache Changes Since Admin Module Using Database directly.Can That  Update process (Cache To  Database)handle in enitity level without involving application?